# Move Android bitmap/canvas away from the top left

Tags: android, bitmap, position, signature, android-canvas

I'm trying to customize some code to capture a signature for my use.  I am new to this stuff and I can't figure it out.
The following code does the job, but the canvas/bitmap is positioned at the top left corner.  I want it somewhere around the upper center part of the page.  I tried to mess around with the drawBitmap parms "canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null)", but it actually creates an offset between the stylus and the actual path drawn on the tablet.

```
Canvas canvas = null;
while (_run) {
    if (isDrawing == true) {
        try {
            canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            if (mBitmap == null) {
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            }
            final Canvas c = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            commandManager.executeAll(c, previewDoneHandler);
            previewPath.draw(c);
            // Rect targetRect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
            // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, targetRect, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        } finally {
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

Is the a way to move the bitmap/canvas to a position other than the top left corner?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, please add the steps you took to resolve your problem as an answer (below), and then _accept_ your answer whenever you're allowed to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I resolved it was by adding the layout_marginLeft and layout_marginTop to my custom view in the xml layout.